# .Net custom listviewitem

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to design and implement custom listviewitem which would be used by the listview in the visual basic.NET (I have downloaded Visual Studio 2017 so I think that I'm using latest visual basic).

I found few pieces of code that shows how to inherit from listviewitem and they work, but they give me only simple effects ([e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826631/create-a-custom-listviewitem-class-to-store-additional-hidden-info-vb-net)).

I would like to achieve following result:

my custom item

[image]

In the given picture Id, Title and Short Desc are considered as labels.

I don't have much vb experience, however I have strong C++/Qt background and I'm bit confused with vb...

Can anyone help and describe the proper way how to do it?

Comment: Are you really tied to WinForms? WPF makes stuff like so much easier - you could simply create the desired layout in xaml.

Comment: For WinForms, it seems like a custom control (or UserControl) on a scrolling panel would be easier

Comment: thx for answers. I'll try both WPF and custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped me with solving the problem.

Done with WPF 
@Filburt: thx for the hint!

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="238" >
        <DockPanel Margin="5,2,2,2">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserBox" Text="{Binding UserId}" Background="{Binding UserColor}" Width="32" Height="32" />
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDesc" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtCreateDate" Text="{Binding CreateDT}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtModifyDate" Text="{Binding ModificationDT}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```